# Issue with mpdf while attachment

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

```
$html = $this->load->view('pdf_output_order_details', $pdf, true);

$pdfFilePath = $pdf['data'][0]->first_name . "_" . $pdf['data'][0]->last_name . ".pdf";

ini_set('error_reporting', E_STRICT);

$this->pdf = $this->m_pdf->load('A4-L');

$this->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

$this->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");
```

While the pdf file is creating successfully if i change to "F" to "D"

But when attchment comes into picture then it throws an error....

"mPDF error: Unable to create output file: abc.pdf"....

I have set all permission to mpdf lib folder and n number of things done but still it won't work.... Please help guys....

Thank You....

Answer (score 0):

I think your $pdfFilepath should containg not only filename, but filepath too.
From mPdf documentation:

> F: save to a local file with the name given by filename (may include a
>   path).

Try this

```
$pdfFilePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files/' . $pdf['data'][0]->first_name . "_" . $pdf['data'][0]->last_name . ".pdf";
```

Of course make sure you have write access to the `files` folder.

Comment: I have try that as well but didin't work same issue exsist.
Which i am working with server that one is Windows Server.

I have given php chmod , permission (0777).

But still problem is alive....

Comment: Is any other way because i have used same code in other server that works smoothly but in windows it crash badly.... Don't know why this problem is there.....

Comment: Set the permission but these warning occur during setting the permission 

Command: SITE CHMOD 755 asset
Response: 500 'SITE CHMOD 755 asset': command not understood

Comment: Ah, you use Windows! Chmod is for linux only! Change rights for this folder from windows aministarion.